# How to add different controls in Gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I know it's possible to change some columns in GridView controls to check boxes and when you are editing certain rows, the cells being hi-lited become text boxes, but supposed I want to add other controls in my gridView. For example: in the image below how would I change the entries of CategoryName to be a dropDown box of possible choices?

[image]

[`[Full size]`](http://www.codersource.net/images/Gridview_depth_Image2.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the TemplateField and define what controls are in your EditItemTemplate.

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx) article as a starting point.